# I want to replace BigInteger for loop in Stream Api

Tags: java, performance, java-stream

Want to replace BigInteger loop in Java Stream API.

Below code, I have to modify in java8 using Stream API. Because of performance concerns.
My question what would be the best practice to change below code into best performance.

```
public BigInteger getSum(BigInteger n, BigInteger c) {
    BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ZERO;
    for (BigInteger i = BigInteger.ZERO; i.compareTo(n) < 0; i=i.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
        sum = sum.add(calculateProduct(i, i.subtract(BigInteger.ONE), c));
    }
    return sum;
}

private BigInteger calculateProduct(BigInteger i, BigInteger j, BigInteger c) {
    if (j.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) < 0) return BigInteger.ZERO;
    if (j.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 0) return BigInteger.ONE;
    if ((i.subtract(j).compareTo(c)) <= 0){
        return j.add(BigInteger.ONE).multiply(calculateProduct(i, j.subtract(BigInteger.ONE), c));
    }else
        return BigInteger.ONE;
}
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? I don't see a few statements but no question mark. If you're trying to convert to the Stream API - what have you tried so far, and where are you stuck? Post the code that you're having a problem with please - the code that you have posted seems to be fine.

Comment: You want to do something like: BigInteger sum = valuesList.stream().reduce((x, y) -> x.add(y)).get()´  ?

Comment: @Erwin Bolwidt this is completed code want change

Comment: @Ravindra Ranwala, could you please help me on this

Comment: @Mark ould you please help me on this

Comment: @ ItFreak could you please help me on this

Comment: I would suggest you using the iterative solution. Which sounds good to me than a stream based one.

Comment: @Ravindra Ranwala could you please give me sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are adding up products of sliding window of width `c`.  If you want to improve performance, get rid of recursion and avoid recomputing the entire product.  Use the product computed in the previous step: multiply it by the number entering the window and divide by the number exiting the window.  Division is slower but it will pay off for larger values of `c`.

Finally, while I will keep your method signature, you really only need `BigInteger` as return.

```
BigInteger getSum(BigInteger n, BigInteger c) {
    BigInteger p = BigInteger.ONE, sum = BigInteger.ZERO;

    for (BigInteger x = BigInteger.ONE; x.compareTo(n) < 0; x = x.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
        p = p.multiply(x);
        if (x.compareTo(c) > 0) {
            p = p.divide(x.subtract(c));
        }
        sum = sum.add(p);
    }

    return sum;
}
```

If you want to speed it up further, you can use a bit of math to avoid having to divide at every step.  Your sum can be broken up into `s1 = sum[1,c) x!` and `s2 = sum[c,n) x!/(x-c)!`.  The second sum equals `n!/(n-c-1)!/(c+1)` (follows from [hockey stick identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490794/proof-of-the-hockey-stick-identity-sum-limits-t-0n-binom-tk-binomn1)).  The method below does not handle the trivial case of c >=n.  I will leave that to you.

```
private static BigInteger fasterSum(BigInteger n, BigInteger c) {
    assert c.compareTo(n) < 0;
    BigInteger sum = ZERO, p = ONE;

    for (BigInteger x = ONE; x.compareTo(c) < 0; x = x.add(ONE)) {
        p = p.multiply(x);
        sum = sum.add(p);
    }

    // sum[c,n) x!/(x-c)! = n!/(n-c-1)!/(c+1)
    p = ONE;
    for (BigInteger x = n.subtract(c); x.compareTo(n) <= 0; x = x.add(ONE)) {
        p = p.multiply(x);
    }
    sum = sum.add(p.divide(c.add(ONE)));

    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I assume you want to add a list of `BigInteger`:
You can do that by using a reduce operation (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html)

```
    List<BigInteger> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(BigInteger.valueOf(5));
            list.add(BigInteger.valueOf(1));
            list.add(BigInteger.valueOf(3));
            list.add(BigInteger.valueOf(10));
            list.add(BigInteger.valueOf(2));

    BigInteger sum = list.stream().reduce((x, y) -> x.add(y)).get();
    System.out.println(sum);
```

That will calculate the sum, an equivalent would be:

```
BigInteger sum = list.stream().reduce(BigInteger::add).get();
```

You could also write an own `Collector` that is reusable and extract the reduce operation to there:

```
public static Collector<BigInteger, ?, BigInteger> calculateSum() {
    return Collectors.reducing(BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger::add);
}
```

and then do:

```
BigInteger sum = list.stream().collect(calculateSum());
```